# More smaller scripts or less larger in Unity 2d Development? Better or worse performance?

Tags: unity, 2d, collision-detection, performance

In my unity 2d game I had large amount of scripts which were components of different enemies and obstacles. All of them were checking for collison, had FixedUpdate, Start and OnCollisionEnter2D and OnCollisionExit2D methods. Now I have implemented most of them into one script which is component of the player.The script is checking for collision and what is the player colliding with.So am i going to get better or worse performance and why?

Comment: If you already have both versions, the easiest would be to just run the profiler and let it tell you if you gained or lost performance.

Comment: Never assume anything about optimization unless a profiler tells you there's a problem. Then use the profiler to find where the problem is.

Comment: I've linked this to a similar question that was asked recently, whose answers discuss the general considerations when working with multiple smaller scripts or larger scripts. If this general advice, combined with the profiling recommended by the comments above, is not enough to help you isolate and solve your problem, then please edit your question to clarify what specific new help you need. Be sure to include the results of your profiling so we can clearly see where is the issue you need help optimizing.